# Is this hadith authentic "Friday is the hajj of poor" Jami'ah-us-Sagheer, p. 221, Hadith 3635)

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Is this hadith authentic from al-Jami'a as-Sagheer الجامع الصغير

> الجمعة حج المساكين or  الجمعة حج الفقراء
>
> Friday is the hajj of poor

Answer (score 1):

This is narrated in Ibn Asakir's Tarikh Dimashq ([38/431](https://shamela.ws/book/71/17361)) and Shaykh Albani classed it Mawd'u (fabricated) in Da'if Jam'i as-Saghir ([2658](https://shamela.ws/book/1663/2652)). By the way, your citing of this narration [p. 211 / #3635] is an error; the correct source of Jam'i as-Saghir from As-Suyuti are the Hadith-Numbers (#[6404](https://shamela.ws/book/21659/6404)/[5](https://shamela.ws/book/21659/6405)).